# java Regex: replace all numerical values with one number

Tags: java, regex, replace, digit

I have a simple line of text which might include numbers like "12.3" or "1983" or "5/8".
Whenever any number appears, I just need to replace with a fixed character, say the digit "8".

I've been fiddling about with Regex in Java, with things like this:

```
String line = str.replaceAll("[0-9]+/*.*[0-9]*", "8");
```

but to no avail.

Any idea what the correct pattern should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this expression: `(?>-?\d+(?:[\./]\d+)?)`, keep in mind that in Java strings you need to escape the backslashes, i.e. you'd get `"(?>-?\\d+(?:[\\./]\\d+)?)"`

Here's a breakdown of the expression:

1. The encloseing `(?>...)` is an atomic group to prevent catastrophic backtracking. For simple or short strings it would work without as well.
2. `-?` a potential minus for negative numbers
3. `\d+` any sequence of digits (at least one)
4. `(?:[\./]\d+)?` an optional non-capturing group consisting of either a dot (note that you don't need to escape it here, it's just for consistency) or a slash followed by at least one more digit.

*Update*

If you don't want to replace "numbers" like `.1234`, `1234.` `/1`  or `5/` (a digit is missing either left or right), try this expression: `(?>(?<![\d\./])-?\d+(?:(?:[\./]\d+)|(?![\d\./])))`

Here's a breakdown again:

1. The encloseing `(?>...)` is an atomic group to prevent catastrophic backtracking. For simple or short strings it would work without as well.
2. `(?<![\d\./])` the match must not directly follow a digit, dot or slash - note that the not follow a digit constraint is needed to match at the start of the number, otherwise you'd match `234` in `.1234`
3. `-?` a potential minus for negative numbers
4. `\\d+` any sequence of digits (at least one)
5. `(?:(?:[\./]\d+)|(?![\d\./]))` the match must either have a dot or slash followed by at least one digit or must not be followed by a digit, dot or slash, this would match `1.0` but not `1.` - note that the not to be followed by a digit constraint is needed to prevent matching `123` in `1234.`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace the whole number with just a single character, use this code:

```
import java.io.*;

class Moo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String vals[] = { "1.2", "-3.14", "100500" };
    for (String s : vals)
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(-)?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?", "x"));
  }
}
```

But if you need to replace each digit, you should use different regex, like this one: `"\\d"`.

See the [demo](http://ideone.com/iX16q).

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to escape the . character. Other than that, your pattern looks good to me.

```
String line = str.replaceAll("[0-9]+/*\\.*[0-9]*", "8");
```

If that still doesn't work, please provide the cases that the expression isn't working correctly on.

Comment: Agreed, but in my experience that kind of behaviour is rarely a problem.