# Replace numbers with string representation

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I am trying to make a program, that displays rather large numbers (BigInteger large). To make it easier for the user, I am displaying the numbers as string (1 000 000 = 1 Million). My below code shows my current attempt. My problem lies, in the fact that the actual number that I am replacing will not be nice and round. This program does not need to **display** the 100% accurate value, rather give a ball park figure. I.E:

```
1 234 567 = 1 Million
1 000 000 = 1 Million
1 934 234 = 1 Million
```

My current code (Shortened for brevity):

```
            if (!displayNumbers) {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(_combinations);
                String t = sb.reverse().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t, 1).show();

                ...

                if (t.contains("000 000 000 000 000")) {
                    t.replace("000 000 000 000 000", "quadrillion");
                }

                if (t.contains("000 000 000 000")) {
                    t.replace("000 000 000 000", "trillion");
                }

                if (t.contains("000 000 000")) {
                    t.replace("000 000 000", "billion");
                }

                if (t.contains("000 000")) {
                    t.replace("000 000", "million");
                }

                sb = new StringBuffer(t);
                _combinations = sb.reverse().toString();
            }
```

I was thinking something along the lines of replacing the zero's with `#'s` so that it would just search for `x lots of 3 digits` and replace with corresponding word, but I do not know how to implement this. I should also note that I am aware that the `million, billion, etc` are currently spelt backwards in the final output string.

EDIT: Should note for UK readers that I am using USA definitions of `*illions`.

EDIT 2: Been doing some more Googling and found this - [java Regex: replace all numerical values with one number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737946/java-regex-replace-all-numerical-values-with-one-number). Except I have no idea how to modify the Regex for finding `000 000`.

Comment: Are your numbers embedded in some large text? Or you are having just that content in your `t` string?

Comment: Just that content. It's displaying high powers E.G. (12312452355^170). And 'Hi' again. You helped a lot on my last question :D

Comment: @Asryael.. You mean you have numbers in the form of powers also?

Comment: No, its displaying the answer of high powers `t = (12312452355^170).toString();` (Psuedo code obviously)

Comment: If you look for just zeros, you won't be able to do e.g. `1 234 567 = 1 Million`. Why not just count the integer digits?

Comment: I will consider that. I currently am attempting to use Regex like this :

`t.replace("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", "million")`

Comment: Why would `1 934 234` be replaced with  `1 Million` and not `2 Million`?

Comment: @RohitJain I would work on doing that after I get basic functionality.

Comment: @Asryael.. Why can't you just do the conversion considering the number as numeral type rather than string. It would be much easier for you. You can make use of `BigInteger` class, and then just compare it with a specific value to decide what value to replace?

Comment: @RohitJain I am attempting to do that now :D I followed MikeM's link, but its for BigDecimals only.

Comment: @Asryael.. Once you get an idea, it won't be difficult to switch between BigDecimal and BigInteger. Try to come up with some code. And then if you face some issue, we are here to help you.

Comment: @RohitJain Okay, worked it out completely will answer myself. Am posting a link to a pastebin copy of full code for anyone's perusal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank everyone else for their help with suggestions on how to fix this, and I am sure that they are all possible. However, I found that the best way, was to still convert the BigInteger to string, but **not** to add whitespace.

If the string's length was less than 6 I left it as it was and simply added whitespace for looks. If it was longer then 6, I took the first 1, 2 or 3 numbers depending on the Mod of the string's length and used them as actual numbers to show at the start (1 Million, 34 Billion, 124 Quadrillion, etc).

This was then followed by seeing how long the remaining string was, and simply adding more string to the display text if it was longer then a certain amount.

If anyone needs clarification of this, please do not hesitate to ask me! Here is the link to the pastebin - http://pastebin.com/3X681UkG

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using if and else statements, from what I understand you're not looking for exact representation , so it is ok to say 1 Million for 1400000.
To do so you can use code like this:

```
int myValue
String txt = null;
if (myValue> 500 000 000){
       txt = String.ValueOf((int) myValue/1000000000) + " Billion"
} else if (myValue> 500 000){
       txt = String.ValueOf((int) myValue/1000000) + " Million"
} else if (myValue> 500) {
       txt = String.ValueOf((int) myValue/1000) + " Thousand"
}
```

This should work for the simple usage you're describing.

Comment: Except for when the value of myValue gets higher then 2^(32-1). Hence the BigIntegers :D

Comment: Yes the same apply to BigInteger , I'm just proposing an idea not implementation

Comment: Okay, but better as e.g. `txt = Math.round(myValue/1e6) + " Million";` and `500 000 000` is invalid, and could be `5e8`. Otherwise, looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Your number(in text) is just for display purpose. It's bad idea to manipulate numbers after converting them to string.

Why don't you just parse the text to integer and format it with a proper way for display.
[Here is a example you should take a look](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html)

Answer (score 0):

Example implementation that rounds numbers over one thousand to one significant figure.

Optionally, groups of three digits may be separated by comma or space.

```
private final static String[] illions = { 
    "m", "b", "tr", "quadr", "quint", "sext", "sept", "oct", "non", "dec",
    "undec", "duodec", "tredec", "quattuordec", "quindec", "sexdec",
    "septendec", "octodec", "novemdec", "vigint", "unvigint", "duovigint", 
    "trevigint", "quattuorvigint", "quinvigint", "sexvigint", "septenvigint",
    "octovigint", "novemvigint", "trigint", "untrigint", "duotrigint" 
};

private static String approximate( String n ) {  
    String approx = n;

    if ( n != null && n.matches( "^\\d{1,3}[\\s,]?(\\d{3}[\\s,]?)*\\d{3}$" ) ) {  
        n = n.replaceAll( "[\\s,]", "" );            
        int i = n.length() + 2;

        if ( i < 105 ) {
            int rnd = (int) Math.round( Double.parseDouble( n.substring( 0, 2 ) ) / 10 )
                    * (int) Math.pow(10, i % 3);
            n = i > 8 ? illions[ i / 3 - 3 ] + "illion" : "thousand";   
            approx = rnd  + " " + n;
        }
    }

    return approx;
}
```

Test

```
System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s",
    approximate("999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"),  // "1000 duotrigintillion"    
    approximate("4857476486598746598743265987426598724365987265987324598726598734625987564987456"),  // "5 quinvigintillion"
    approximate("56843584275874587243582837465847326554"),  // "60 undecillion"
    approximate("1 345 678 910 111 213"),                   // "1 quadrillion"
    approximate("47,648,658,437,651"),                      // "50 trillion"
    approximate("9 891 011 123"),                           // "10 billion"
    approximate("687654321"),                               // "700 million"
    approximate("32 456 999"),                              // "30 million"
    approximate("2,678,910"),                               // "3 million"
    approximate("1 234 567"),                               // "1 million"
    approximate("123456"),                                  // "100 thousand"
    approximate("17,654"),                                  // "20 thousand"
    approximate("8765"),                                    // "9 thousand"
    approximate("654")                                      // "654"
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would just simply count digits. rough code from scratch:

```
String result = "";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\s0-9]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(t);
int index = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    int newIndex = matcher.start();
    result += t.substring(index, newIndex);
    result += convert(matcher.group());

    index = matcher.end() + 1;
}

result += t.substring(index, t.length() - 1);


private String convert(String uglyNumber) {

    // get rid of whitespaces
    String number = uglyNumber.replace("\\s", "");

    // simply count digits
    if( 6 < number.length() && number.length() <= 9 ) {
    return "million";
    } else if( 9 < number.length() && number.length() <= 12 ) {
        return "million";
    } else ...

    return ulgyNumber;
}
```

if numbers are more compilcated than simple mix of digits and whitespaces, you may want to have a look for this [regex site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html):